# Need help setting up a conditional in JSX

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ternary-operator

I am iterating a block of JSX code that is getting its data from a json file, and is being displayed to the DOM. I need to apply a style to the first iteration in my map function but the rest need to be blank.

The training variable holds data from my json file. I need to apply a style of "marginRight:'5%'" to the first iteration of this map method.

**trainer.js**

```
{ training.map((course, index) => {     
  return (
    <Course name={course.name}
        school={course.school}
        location={course.location}
        year={course.year}
        class={classes}
        key={index}

        style={{marginRight: '5%'}}  <- this works but applies the style to all courses, which is not what I want.

    />
  )
})}
```

**trainerTemplate.js** - This is the template that gets rendered. Props gets passed here from trainer.js

```
function Course(props){
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Grid item style={props.style}>
```

I'm assuming I need to set up a ternary operator somewhere that checks for an index of 0, but I can't seem to get anything to work

Comment: did you try `{{index === 0 ? marginRight: '5%' : ''}}` - you have the index there so you know when you are on 0. Use that. (pseudo code. you might need a little rearranging to make this work but this is how you would compare in JSX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is as same as @Kai Qing ansewr

```
{ training.map((course, index) => {     
  return (
    <Course name={course.name}
        school={course.school}
        location={course.location}
        year={course.year}
        class={classes}
        key={index}
style={{marginRight: index === 0 ? '5%' : ''
  }}  
    />
  )
})}
```

Comment: Almost. You have your ternary in the value of marginRight, which I bet is the correct way. I don't work in JSX often so I forget, but I am familiar enough to know it's something like this.

Comment: Would it be better should the default value to `0` instead of an empty string?  `marginRight: index === 0 ? marginRight: '5%' : '0'`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys but its not working for me. Kai Qing, your example, it shows a red underline (error) under === and : but with Muhammad's example, its giving me an error under :

Comment: How about `{{marginRight: (index === 0 ? marginRight: '5%' : '0')
  }}`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't like that else : statement    :-(

Comment: @Sung M. Kim Yes, but in case if a person is using another margin then it will overwrite that.

Comment: Nope. Visual studio code is showing a red underline under the else : statement

Comment: @learnerforlife make sure that there are two closing curly brackets:

`
    style={{marginRight: index === 0 ? '5%' : ''}}  
`

Comment: style={{marginRight: index === 0 ? '5%' : ''}} Works!

Comment: @learnerforlife Perfect! Feel free to select it as answer -- thank you!

Comment: @MuhammadUsman That's definitely a valid reason. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 3):

Try this, I think it's a little clearer than doing it inline:

```
{ training.map((course, index) => {
  const style = index === 0 ? { marginRight: '5%' } : null; // then use this as the style later
  return (
    <Course 
        name={course.name}
        school={course.school}
        location={course.location}
        year={course.year}
        className={classes} // also change this to className, not class
        key={index} // if you can, avoid using the index as the key
        style={style}  
    />
  )
})}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you conditionally want to set margin for first item alone, you can try this: This one passes style attr for firstone, and refrains from over-writing previously set margin if in case index doesn't belong to the first element.

```
{training.map((course, index) => {
  return (
    <Course
      name={course.name}
      school={course.school}
      location={course.location}
      year={course.year}
      class={classes}
      key={index}
      style={index === 0 ? { marginRight: "5%" } : {}}
   />
  );
})}
```